What is the equivalent of the asyncdata hook in Nuxt 3 for SvelteKit?
I just started learning SvelteKit and need to know the hook that does the same thing asyncdata does in Nuxt3 which is:

If a user makes a request to get a page and the request gets to the server first (The person refreshed the page), an API call made from the server gets the needed content and places it as part of the page. When the page is sent to the user, the client will not make the same API call since the server already did it.

If the user is already on the page and navigates to another page, an API call is made from the client to get information needed on the next page.


In SvelteKit there are two load methods which depend on the file used:
+page.server.ts or +page.ts.
+page.server.ts always runs on the server. Even if the user navigates to another page, the client will make a request to the server before executing what is written in the +page.server.ts file.
+page.ts comes close to what I want but it's not exactly what I want. If the request gets to the server first, the server will execute the code in that file and send the complete page to the client but the client also runs the same code which is unnecessary. The good news is that subsequent calls will be made from the client and not the server.
So, my question is, is there a way to have only the server or only the client run the code depending on which one (server or client) received the request for a page?

You can use either load function, it primarily depends on whether the API call can be made from the client directly.
The LoadEvent has a fetch function that prevents duplicate requests. See last two points of the documentation:

fetch is equivalent to the native fetch web API, with a few additional features:

It can be used to make credentialed requests on the server, as it inherits the cookie and authorization headers for the page request.
It can make relative requests on the server (ordinarily, fetch requires a URL with an origin when used in a server context).
Internal requests (e.g. for +server.js routes) go directly to the handler function when running on the server, without the overhead of an HTTP call.
During server-side rendering, the response will be captured and inlined into the rendered HTML by hooking into the text and json methods of the Response object. Note that headers will not be serialized, unless explicitly included via filterSerializedResponseHeaders
During hydration, the response will be read from the HTML, guaranteeing consistency and preventing an additional network request.



I just did this and can confirm that only the server made the request, the client developer tools did not show any request made by the browser. But, every console.log statement I wrote executed on both the server and the client. I'm also going to be writing logs in the load function. I don't want 2 different logs being written. Is there a hook that stops duplication in its entirety and not just for making requests?

Not that I know of. You could potentially extract all logic that should only happen once into an API endpoint (+server.js) and access that using fetch to deduplicate.

Then I might as well just use the +page.server.ts Thank you for helping me. At least, I now know that it simply can’t be done in sveltekit.

@Victor: You could open a SvelteKit issue and e.g. suggest adding a hydrating flag to the PageLoad event.
